# How to check for Array in Database CodeIgniter and if they don't exist Add them

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-select2, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

So I just want to insert the data if the typed data does not exist and/or remove them if users decides to remove them; the problem is that it checks for more **> 1** value.

This should be my last question of three in total(see my last two question on profile) regarding the same topic, relationships.

So I have three tables like the ones given below:

AI = auto increment.

**ci_users:** user_id(AI), username, slug, email, biography.

**ci_terms:** term_id(AI), title, slug, body.

**ci_relationship:** id(AI), term_id, user_id, type.

I'm actually trying to do this in a edit view in which I get all the terms from ci_terms and and the already(added directly in databse) ci_terms attached to the user with the following controller:

```
public function edit($id){

    // Verify user ID before updating/editing info
    if($this->session->userdata('user_id') != $id) {
        // Redirect to dashboard
        redirect('users/dashboard');
    }

    // Field Rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[7]|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        // Get user
        $data['item'] = $this->User_model->get($id);

        // Meta
        $data['title']  = $this->settings->title.' | Edit '. ucfirst($data['item']->username);

        // Get attached skills
        $skills = array();
        $skills[0] = 'Select Skills';

        $skills_attached = $this->User_model->the_skills($id);

        foreach($skills_attached as $skill){
            $skills[$skill->term_id] = $skill->term_id;
        }

        $data['skills'] = $skills;

        // Select Skills    
        $skill_options = array();
        $skill_options[0] = 'Select Skills';

        $skill_list = $this->Terms_model->get_list();

        foreach($skill_list as $cat){
            $skill_options[$cat->term_id] = $cat->title;
        }

        $data['skill_options'] = $skill_options;

        //Load View Into Template
        $this->template->load('public', 'default', 'users/edit', $data);

    } else {

        // Create User Data Array
        $data = array(
            'email'      => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
            'biography'  => strip_tags($this->input->post('biography')),
        );

        // Update User
        $this->User_model->update($id, $data);

        // BEGINNING OF HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP

        // Here I try to check the selected ci_terms(term_id) in the database
        $existent_skill = $this->User_model->existent_skill($this->input->post('term_id'));

        // If the selected ci_terms(term_id) already exists, display an error
        if (!empty($existent_skill)) {

            // Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You already have that one or more of those selected skills');

            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('users/edit/'.$id.'/'.$id->username);

        } else {

            // Display the data from ci_terms table
            $skills = $this->Terms_model->get_list();

            // Expect data to be array
            $data = array();

            foreach ($skills as $skill){
                $data[] = array(
                    // The main problem how do I add the correct IDs to the array?
                    'term_id'   => $skill->id,
                    'user_id'   => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                    'type'      =>  'skill',
                );
            }

            // If terms selected, add them
            $this->db->insert_batch('ci_relationship', $data);

            // I'm also trying to figure out a way to remove the terms that are already attached to the user if he/she decides not to want those skill anymore, any suggestion will be taken into practice.
            // else if terms unselected, remove them
            $this->User_model->delete_skills($id, $terms_id, $data);

            // END OF HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP

        }

        // Create Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "You're account has been updated");

        // Redirect to profile
        redirect('users/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Here is how I get to display the attached(to user) terms from the ci_terms table into the view:

```
public function the_skills($id){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->relationship);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('type', 'skill');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() >= 1){
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the method which I'm still trying to create that checks for all the selected terms before adding them if they don't exist:

```
// Verify if relationship already exists
public function existent_skill($term_id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->relationship, array(
        'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'term_id' => $term_id,
        'type' => 'skill',
    ));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

to continue, here is the function which is supposed(not tested) to delete them if they're unselected from the input:

```
// Delete un-selected skills
public function delete_skills($id, $terms_id, $data){
    $this->db->from($this->relationship);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $this->db->where_in('term_id', $terms_id);
    $this->db->where('type', 'skill');

    $this->db->delete($this->relationship, $data);
}
```

Finally here is the view in which I'm using a dropdown with select2:

```
<!-- Skills -->
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Skills', 'skills'); ?>
    <div class="input-group date"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <?php
                $data = array(
                    'id'        => 'term_id[]',
                    'name'      => 'term_id[]',
                );
                $class = array(
                    'class'     =>  'form-control js-example-basic-multiple',
                    'multiple'  => TRUE,
                );
            ?>
            <!-- $data is to provide the dropdown with the id and name -->
            <!-- $skill_options is to get the terms from ci_terms in case the user wants to add them as their skill -->
            <!-- $skills is to get the current term_id attached to the user which were added in the db -->
            <!-- $class is to give the class of js-example-basic-multiple to enable select2 -->
            <?= form_dropdown($data, $skill_options, $skills, $class); ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            // Select2 Input
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
                    tags: true,
                    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
allowClear: true,
    selectOnClose: false,
    selectOnBlur: false,
                });
            });
            </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**BELOW ARE JUST IMAGES**

So what I'm trying to achieve is this:
[image: expected value]

As you can see there HTML5(term_id, 1) and CSS(term_id, 2) are the attached term_id's and if I deselect them, they should be deleted from ci_relationship after clicking the update button and the same(not really) goes when selecting new terms that are not attached, they should be added.

Is pretty much a relationship system like the one WordPress uses.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are overthinking here to much - you should just delete all items related to that user and after that insert the new ones which are selected...

an example for your model function could be

```
public function updateSkills(array $arrSkills)
{
    //in case if the array is empty you can stop the process here
    if (empty($arrSkills))  return false;

    //kill all associated items
    $this->db
        ->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'))
        ->where('type', 'skill');
        ->delete('ci_relationship');

    //insert all items
    $arrInsertData = [];

    foreach($arrSkills AS $strSkill)
    {
        $arrInsertData[] = [
            'term_id' => $strSkill,
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'type' => 'skill'
        ]
    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('ci_relationship', $arrInsertData);

    return true;
}
```

and the part in your controller could look like

```
$data = array(
    'email'      => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
    'biography'  => strip_tags($this->input->post('biography')),
);

// Update User
$this->User_model->update($id, $data);

// BEGINNING OF HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
$blnSuccess = $this->User_model->updateSkills($this->input->post('term_id[]'));
```

of course you can also add a rule, in case if `term_id` is required

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('term_id[]', 'Term', 'trim|required');
```

Comment: I damn love you dude!, thanks it works like a charm :)